# Moving all files recursively from subfolders to parent

Tags: macos, file, recursion, terminal

I have a folder called "Music" which is my parent folder. This folder contains alot of .mp3- and .m4a-files, some in the root of the folder and others in subfolders that can have several subfolders.

How do I use terminal on my Mac to recursively move all files from the subfolder, up into the root of my Music folder and replace existing/duplicate files?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using `find`

Comment: I know how to use find, my problem right now is moving the files found using find :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. have a good backup ;-) **Seriously!**
2. `cd` to your `Music` folder
3. type `find . -type f -iname '*.mp3' -mindepth 2 -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv -n '{}' .`

Comment: Not what you were looking for?